# Proving bijectivity in fourth isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group, $N$ a normal subgroup in $G$. Moreover, let $F = \{A \subseteq G \: | \: A \leq G, \: N \subseteq A\}$, and $H = \{ A \subseteq G/N \: | \: A \leq G/N\}$. I want to prove that there exists a bijection from $F$ to $H$. In order to do so I considered the natural projection of $F$ into $H$:

$ \pi: F \rightarrow H, \: A \mapsto A/N$.

Clearly this map is surjective. However I am struggling to prove that it's injective. This was my attempt:

Let $A,B \in F$. Suppose we have $A/N = B/N$; we wish to show that $A=B$:

Firstly, we will show that $ A \subseteq B$:

$\subseteq $: Let $a \in A$ then $aN=bN$ for some $b \in B$. Thus $a \in bN$, meaning $a$ is a coset represetative for $bN$ also. However, this doesn't necessarily mean that $a \in B$.

I am unable to therefore show that $a$ is in $B$. I believe proving that $B \subseteq A$ would follow by symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't used that $N\leq B$. So $a\in bN\subseteq bB=B$ since for any $c\in B$ we have $c=b b^{-1}c\in bB$.

Comment: You are, of course, correct that the converse statement follows by symmetry.